# How can i give the weights to the variable in python randomforest

Tags: python, variables, random-forest

I made the randomforest classifier model.
It has about 100 X variables(features) to classify Y(angle).
I want to give weights to some important features.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *class_weight* parameter to achieve this, if you are using sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier in the form of

```
class_weight = {class_label_0: class_weight_0,
                class_label_1: class_weight_1}
```

following that important features gets higher weights than other that aren't that important.

You can check this more detailed in [SKLearn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) in the parameters section of class weight.